# iOS Screen Recorder shows error of Media Service failure, after my own app stops receiving video buffers from RPScreenRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit, rpscreenrecorder

So here is the scenario I am going through.
My app records screen and Mic Audio through RP`RPScreenRecorder` using it's function `startCaptureWithHandler:completionHandler:`.
For A brief review I am writing down the pseudocode of my app

```
videoWriter = videoWriter (videoInput(config))
audioWriter = audioWriter (audioInput(config))
RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder.startCaptureWithHandler{
(captureBuffer,bufferType,error)
//if video buffer, adds to videoInput and 
//writes through video writer, same for audioWriter 
}completionHandler{
}
```

after completion of desired recording, i call `stopCaptureWithHandler:`.

Some times it so happens that I stop getting  video buffer from the `startCaptureWithHandler:` and just getting audio buffer (Even if I am doing changes on screen)

If this happens, I go to System screen Recorder [image: screenRec image]

and this error comes

[image: error]

my question is, Can my code/app contribute in this error, my app flow is simple and I am unable to find out any potential reason? or iOS is responsible of this error and showing the error after frequent recording?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found out the answer of this particular problem.
I've already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307215/6212787)

**TLDR;**

This problem occurs when you stop recording immediately after starting the capture.