# Recording interrupted by multitasking and content resizing

Tags: swift, ios12, replaykit, rpscreenrecorder

A try to start a screen recording with RPScreenRecorder. I got the following error:

> Recording interrupted by multitasking and content resizing

```
func startRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    recorder.startRecording(handler: { (error) in
        if let unwrappedError = error {
            print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
        } else {

        }
    })
}
```

Before iOS 12.0 everything worked fine. From the update I get the error above.

Comment: Same issue happening with my iphone 6 and 6 plus, other seem to work fine

Comment: Had the same issue and it did work after restarting the device. But the whole replaykit is very fragile and buggy.

Comment: @MaciejS , it will come again after sometimes of restart, if you use the replay kit often

Comment: Same prob here on an iPhoneX

Comment: I had to delete the app and then shut the phone down for 30 minutes then this problem went away. I'm sure it will be back though, no doubt.

Comment: I've deleted the app and re-install again but still facing this issue. :'(

Answer (score 1):

My app has been rejected from App store for the same reason. So far the only workaround is to reboot the device.

Comment: Can you please share with us their reasoning when they rejected?

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan They thought that this error message was related to Network because it was easily reproducible in wifi condition. So they asked me to check the network handling. Removing the  animation during  recording can reduce the frequency of this bug but it can still happen inconsistently.

Comment: I've done a lot of research on the errors and posted the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440249/replaykit-startcapturewithhandler-not-sending-cmsamplebufferref-of-video-type

For now my screen recording feature is bug free. But who knows what comes with the new OS updates

Comment: @TalhaAhmadKhan I agree with you that it might be related to UI prompt because on my side it used to happen when the permission alert ("Allow screen recording in appName") was supposed to be displayed.  Unfortunately there is no way to delay the alert display.

Comment: I was also facing same issue and I found a strange solution for this. After permission alert  and I restarted device and this error do not come again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here is how I solved it.
go to project then targets then capability switch on Background mode then enable audio and VOIP. It should work

Comment: I have tried this steps. Didnt work for me. In Addition to this two steps I restarted xCode and reboot device. This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of research on the errors and posted the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307215/6212787).

For now my screen recording feature is bug free. But who knows what comes with the new OS updates

Answer (score 0):

We've been rejected same issue several times.

But we found a senario to re-produce as bellow,
We reported it on Resolution Center in App Store Connect, then passed.

1. connect iOS(12.4) device to host launched XCode 10.3
   (regardless of opened related project)
2. cold boot iOS device.
3. launch app and start recording video ASAP(until 30sec after booted)

Now iOS13, we don't face this error at the above senario.